# Hiding items (nodes) in a cross site collection top navigation based on profile property (Audiences)

Tags: 2013, navigation, user-profile-property, top-link-bar, audiences

I have followed this article to create a cross site Collection top navigation and it works greate.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897739(v=office.14).aspx
```

I go through all Site Collections and add them to the top navigation. Now I want to hide one or two of the items (nodes = site collections) based on users Office profile property (office property contains the location of the user). I have created an Audience in CA but I don't know how can I implement it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is SharePoint 2013 limitation and as you can read in Tobias blog, there is even more issues with Top navigation.
But if anyone can provide custom solution for this I am willing even to buy it.

Thanks to Tobias blog:
http://blog.lekman.com/2013/01/limitations-with-managed-metadata.html